# What is the maximum limit of suspension on the 'Physics' Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, support, suspensions

Today I came across an account ([link removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions)) which had been suspended for a very long time.

> Is there any other instances for such suspensions?

> What are the probable reasons of very long time suspension?

> Do anybody thinks that it's worthy or important to create a system set up which will generate some automated messages that will warn the users from doing such things or to acknowledge the moderator on this type of activities?

Comment: There *is* already a system for warning users away from behaviour that could result in a >1yr suspension. Those are only reached after the user has received multiple shorter suspensions, with clear explanations about why they were imposed, and the user nevertheless repeats the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Regular suspensions (issued by site moderators) usually last 7, 30 or 365 days, depending on how severe the offense was and the user's history. See [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/); this also includes some common reasons for suspensions.

However, this user has received a network-wide suspension from the site owners, and those can last longer:

> #### What is a network-wide suspension?
>
> A network-wide suspension is applied to all network accounts of a user. It can only be issued by Stack Exchange employees and can be longer than 365 days. The most common reasons for a network-wide suspension are spamming, trolling, and [to cool down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323442/364003).

(source: the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125271/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange)

> Do anybody thinks that it's worthy or important to create a system set up which will generate some automated messages that will warn the users from doing such things or to acknowledge the moderator on this type of activities?

If it's just a minor offense, the moderators will usually first issue a warning instead of suspending. So that system is already in place.

Comment: But he has been suspended for more than  10 years. Why that happened? I want to know any proper reason for that? Can you explain any similar cas?

Comment: @David As you can read in the duplicates I linked to your question, any suspension longer than 1 year is imposed by SE employees and not moderators. As you can read in the post I linked under "link removed" in your question, we (both moderators and SE employees) do not usually publicly discuss any more details of suspensions than are already visible to you anyway.

Comment: It [can be approx. 274 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years-and-cannot#comment1059459_284807) (99,999 days)